# What's the use of OSchedule in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I saw the calls OSchedule listed in my console but I've no idea on how to interact with It. Can I register new function call schedule ? I've found no documentation on the subject. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSchedule is an internal Class of OrientDB where you can register a cron expression to the automatic execution of an OFunction.

```
INSERT INTO oschedule
  SET name = 'session',
      function = (SELECT FROM ofunction WHERE name = 'listSession'),
      rule = \"0/2 * * * * ?\"
```

It's help full when you want to regular check or cleaning of the some data.